# How do I move the starting point of X,Y coordinates plotted on a circle perimeter?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I want to plot a range of points on the lower left section (6 to 9 o'clock) of the perimeter of a circle. However, the starting point of rendering X,Y coordinates always begins at 3 o'clock.
!https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55849501/plotting-xy.png

Here is the rendering portion of my code:

```
var items = 5;
for(var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    var x = 96 + 100 * Math.cos(0.665 * Math.PI * i / items);
    var y = 96 + 100 * Math.sin(0.665 * Math.PI * i / items);   
    $("#center").append("<div class='point' style='left:"+ x +"px;top:"+ y +"px'></div>");    
}
```

And here is a jsfiddle of the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jE26S/198/

In summary:
I want the points to render starting at the 6 o'clock position instead of the 3 o'clock position.

Comment: Since the screen-coords have the y axis flipped (in relation to the cartesion coord system), the circle is indeed drawn in an anti-clockwise direction. Since 6oclock pos is 1/4 of a circle after the 3oclock pos, you just need to add 90 degrees to the term used for sin and/or cos. I.e add ( (90/180) * Math.Pi) to the value passed to the trig functions. (PI/2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are really doing here is interpolating between two values of theta. In your case, you want to start at Pi/2 and end at Pi. I took the liberty of re-writing your snippet using this interpolation paradigm. Also, you can adjust how far you want the dots/items away from the circle using outerCircleRadius.

```
var items = 5;
var startTheta = .5 * Math.PI;
var endTheta = 1 * Math.PI;
var outerCircleRadius = 112;
var cx = 90;
var cy = 90;
for(var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    var theta = startTheta + (endTheta - startTheta) * i / (items - 1)
    var x = cx + outerCircleRadius * Math.cos(theta);
    var y = cy + outerCircleRadius * Math.sin(theta);   
    $("#center").append("<div class='point' style='left:"+ x +"px;top:"+ y +"px'></div>");    
}
```

Comment: Great answer and very thorough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
var x = 86 + 100 * Math.cos(0.665 * Math.PI * (items-1+i-0.5) / items);
var y = 96 + 100 * Math.sin(0.665 * Math.PI * (items-1+i-0.5) / items);
```

Comment: Upvote for your answer because it is so simple and close to what I asked. But not as flexible as @richard shurtz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in Richard Shurtz's answer, except for the "items - 1" in the first line in the loop.

This worked for any number of items:

```
var items = 5;
var startTheta = .5 * Math.PI;
var endTheta = 1 * Math.PI;
var outerCircleRadius = 112;
var cx = 90;
var cy = 90;
for(var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    var theta = startTheta + (endTheta - startTheta) * i / items
    var x = cx + outerCircleRadius * Math.cos(theta);
    var y = cy + outerCircleRadius * Math.sin(theta);   
    $("#center").append("<div class='point' style='left:"+ x +"px;top:"+ y +"px'></div>");    
}
```